# material ui button icon is not appearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

the button is working but the icon inside it is not working:
[image]

the button code:

```
 <Button color="secondary" aria-label="add an alarm">
<AlarmIcon></AlarmIcon>
</Button>
<Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<AlarmIcon />}>
  Delete
</Button>
```

the button imports:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AlarmIcon from '@mui/material/Icon';
```

the full code example:

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AlarmIcon from '@mui/material/Icon';

const App = () => {
  const url = "https://api.quotable.io/random";
  let quoteData = {
    content: "Let time be your only competitor.",
    author: "Ahmed Saber"
  }
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState(quoteData)
 
  const generateQuote = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        setQuote(data)
      });
  }

  const copy = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(quote.author + " once said: " + quote.content)
    alert('copied')
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Quote Generator React App</h1>
      
      <div className="container">
        <p>{quote.content}</p>
        <span>{quote.author}</span>
        <div className="btns">
          <button onClick={copy} className="btn">Copy</button>
          <button onClick={generateQuote}>Generate Another Quote</button>
       
          
        </div>
        <Button color="secondary" aria-label="add an alarm">
<AlarmIcon></AlarmIcon>
</Button>
<Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<AlarmIcon />}>
  Delete
</Button>
      </div>
    </>

  )
  
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the `IconButton` and use it like this:

```
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton/IconButton'
import AlarmIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Alarm'

<IconButton
  aria-label="..."
  size="small"
  onClick={() => ...}
>
  <AlarmIcon sx={{ color: 'blue' }} />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: I don't understand the onClick part, why do we need it?

Comment: I used Iconbutton previously but didn't generate anything

Comment: The onClick is a anonymous function in this case. But it's just an example. You can also specify a function of you component

Comment: Hhhmm.. maybe an issue of the colors? Can you see something when you change the background to white?

Comment: Or try to change the color of the icon with `sx={{ color: 'blue' }}`

Comment: both didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<Button
      variant="outlined" 
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <AlarmIcon />
        )
        }}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement probably needs to be updated to

```
import AlarmIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Alarm';
```

Using latest Material Icons I had to update the import

my versions for MUI and MUI icons

```
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.17",
```

Comment: this gives me error:'module not found'

Comment: check your packages.json to see which which material icons you have installed (assuming you're using npm).  This will install the latest: `npm install @mui/icons-material` and you will be able to use '@mui/icons-material/Alarm' import

Comment: sorry, `npm install @mui/icons-material@latest` to make sure you're installing the latest